# Saving results of plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931 with higher resolution

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am using the `colour` library in python.

I am calling `plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931` as such:

```
fig, axes = plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(RGB=RGB, scatter_kwargs={'c': colors, 'marker': '.', 'label': "e"}, filename='e.jpeg', dpi=8000, show_pointer_gamut=False)
```

No matter what `filename` format I pass, I cannot get a higher resolution. `dpi` does not appear to do anything. `fig.dpi`, once returned, shows `200.0` no matter what I pass.

Is there a way around this? How can I save at a higher resolution?

Is it possible for me to edit the `dpi` after the fact and save it?

Answer (score 0):

`Colour` will honour the settings that are set in `Matplotlib` `rcParams` so you could do something like that:

```py
import colour
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.rc_context(
    {
        "figure.figsize": (20.48, 20.48),
        "figure.dpi": 100,
        "savefig.dpi": 100,
    }
):
    figure, axes = colour.plotting.plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
        RGB=np.random.random((32, 32, 3)),
        filename="/Users/kelsolaar/Downloads/high-dpi.jpeg",
        show_pointer_gamut=False,
    )
```

An alternative is to create the figure at the desired resolution and pass its axes to the plotting definition:

```py
figure = plt.figure(figsize=(20.48, 20.48))

figure, axes = colour.plotting.plot_RGB_chromaticities_in_chromaticity_diagram_CIE1931(
    axes=figure.gca(),
    RGB=np.random.random((32, 32, 3)),
    filename="/Users/kelsolaar/Downloads/high-dpi-alternative.jpeg",
    show_pointer_gamut=False,
)
```